# Saving User Inputs into a List in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, raw-input

I want to prompt the user for a list of phrases over and over again until they input `END` and save all of the user's inputs into a list. How can I do that?

My code so far:

```
print("Please input passwords one-by-one for validation.")
userPasswords = str(input("Input END after you've entered your last password.", \n))
boolean = True
while not (userPasswords == "END"):
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`list(iter(input, 'END'))`

Comment: @KevinGuan: You nailed it.  Who could find a more concise solution?

Comment: @Alex i have edited OP with code

Comment: @zondo: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Oh wait, I do have another one. Edited.

Comment: Try a while loop first to understand the necessary logic. Then feel free to play with the solution by @KevinGuan

Comment: @KevinGuan that is why I love Python - pretty

Comment: @KevinGuan: Yeah, I guess you nailed it deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is with a `while loop`:

```
phraseList = []

phrase = input('Please enter a phrase: ')

while phrase != 'END':
    phraseList.append(phrase)
    phrase = input('Please enter a phrase: ')

print(phraseList)
```

Result:

```
>>> Please enter a phrase: first phrase
>>> Please enter a phrase: another one
>>> Please enter a phrase: one more
>>> Please enter a phrase: END
>>> ['first phrase', 'another one', 'one more']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [`iter(input, 'END')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), which returns a `callable_iterator`. Then we can use `list()` to get a *real* list:

```
>>> l = list(iter(input, 'END'))
foo
bar
foobar
END
>>> l
['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
```

About how does it work, if you take a look at `help(iter)`:

```
iter(...)
    iter(iterable) -> iterator
    iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator

    Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
    supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
    In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.
```

---

You can also use a `while` loop if you think it's more simple and clear anyway:

```
l = []
while True:
    password = input()
    if password != 'END':
        l.append(password)
    else:
        break
```

Demo:

```
>>> l = []
>>> while True:
...     password = input()
...     if password != 'END':
...         l.append(password)
...     else:
...         break
...         
...     
... 
foo
bar
END
>>> l
['foo', 'bar']
```